# QTableWidget slot not calling function (argent)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

**.h**

```
public slots:   
    void actCopy();
    void recordlocation(int,int);
```

**_moc.cc**

```
case 6: _t->actCopy();break;
case 7: _t->recordlocation((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1])),(*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[2]))); break;
        default: ;
        }
```

**.cc**

```
connect(ui->actionCopy1,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(actCopy()));
connect(ui->previewTable,SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(recordlocation(int, int)));

void
TimeSchedulerWindow::actCopy()
{   
    copy_cell(loc.row,loc.column);

}
void 
TimeSchedulerWindow::recordlocation(int row, int column)
{
    loc.row=row;
    loc.column=column;
    copy_cell(loc.row,loc.column);
}
```

other slot in my program is work....
only this two slot not work..
I like calling `slot()` not calling the function
Anyone can help?

Comment: What type is actionCopy1 and previewTable?  And are the slots defined as private or public slots, and are they being connected to from inside another class, or inside the same class?

Comment: The problem solve....because the moc file not generate from .h is from _ui.h......the compile duno the slot added inside .h